# URL fails in W3C HTML/XHTML Validation

Tags: validation, url, xhtml, w3c

I use the URL below in my web page in **href** tag and unfortunatelly whole link fails in W3C HTML/XHTML Validation.

How do I solve this problem?

```
http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=N+Z&hl=en&hnear=ABC+N4+1,+Jamaica&t=m&z=16
```

*My page includes:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
.
.
.
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you included the validation error

Comment: + is not a valid URL character change it to %2B

Comment: Reference not terminated by REFC delimiter. - Reference to external entity in attribute value. - An unknown entity has been used. This often happens when &param=value is used instead of &amp;param=value in URL query strings - In HTML the ampersand character (&) is reserved for marking character entities so you should never use raw ampersands in HTML - including ampersands inside URLs. For example, any URL that needs an ampersand should look like:
http://www.example.com/file.html?var1=val1&amp;var2=val2&amp;var3=val3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to encode the ampersand (`&`) in URLs with `&amp;`.

So your URL should look like:

`http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=N+Z&amp;hl=en&amp;hnear=ABC+N4+1,+Jamaica&amp;t=m&amp;z=1`

See info in [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#ampersands-in-uris), for example. Also there is web tool which checks for ambiguous ampersands: http://mothereff.in/ampersands

Answer (score 2):

You should escape/encode the URL.